# How to return value with the same name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have database name: **db_test**

and table: **data**

```
**id**         **name** 
1              Conference_Option
2              Conference_Name
3              Conference_Capacity
4              Sip_Name
```

I want to return all with **Conference** in name

This is my code

```
SELECT *
FROM sys3.pages
where name_english = "Conference*"
```

but it has no return

thanks :)

Comment: use `SELECT * FROM sys3.pages where name_english like 'Conference%'` . SQL101

Comment: nice one thanks @Utsav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM sys3.pages where name_english like 'Conference%'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a %Like% operators,

%abc -End with 'abc'
abc% -start with 'abc'
%abc% -in between with 'abc'

Your answer is,

```
SELECT * FROM sys3.pages where name_english like 'Conference%'
```